# Make an Ajax call on button press but not too often

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple javascript counter that increases whenever the user clicks a right arrow button and decreases when the user clicks the left arrow.  I need to make an Ajax call to a PHP page which saves it in a database.  I've got two methods to work, but neither is ideal.

Method #1: I make the ajax call every single time the user clicks.  The problem here is that sometimes the user might click the right arrow 5 times in one second.  Now javascript starts making a bunch of calls and can't keep up.  It puts unnecessary load on the client and server.

Method #2: I only make the call and save the final value when the user clicks to close the pop-up window that contains the counter.  The problem here is that the user may navigate away from the page, lose connectivity, or press refresh and the ajax call never gets sent.

My basic function to make the ajax call is here:

```
function saveNum(num) {

var urlString = "http://example.com/save_counter.php?num="+num;
$.ajax({
        url:urlString,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            $('#status_messages').notify("problem with ajax call", { position:"top", className:"warn" });
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); }
```

Any suggestions on the best way to design this?
Someone said that my exact issue was already addressed in this other thread.
[How to rate-limit clicks on a button to once per minute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550150/how-to-rate-limit-clicks-on-a-button-to-once-per-minute-in-javascript)
But my issue is different.  In the other solution, those users are forced to only make their Ajax call once per minute.  I can't force my users to only click the right and left arrows at a certain interval.  They need to be able to click freely.  I just need javascript to handle it gracefully so as to not lose the data and not make unnecessary ajax calls.

**Answer:**

The question was marked as duplicate. But as it was said, this issue is different. I think I have a solution to this problem, but since I can't post an answer I just edit the original question.

Try this:

```
<script>
// original saveNum() function
function saveNum(num) {
    var urlString = "http://example.com/save_counter.php?num="+num;
    $.ajax({
        url:urlString,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            $('#status_messages').notify("problem with ajax call", { position:"top", className:"warn" });
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 0;
    var wait_for = 3000;//miliseconds

    //left arrow event
    $("#left_arrow").click(function(){
        num--; //decrement num
        $("#acct_num").html( num ); //show acct num to user
        if( typeof timeout !== "undefined" ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout ); //clear timeout if it is defined
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( saveNum, wait_for, num ); //set new timeout
    });

    //right arrow event
    $("#right_arrow").click(function(){
        num++; //increment num
        $("#acct_num").html( num );  //show acct num to user
        if( typeof timeout !== "undefined" ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout ); //clear timeout if it is defined
        }
        timeout = setTimeout( saveNum, wait_for, num ); //set new timeout
    });

    //save num when user exit page before timeout
    $(window).unload(function() {
        saveNum(num);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="left_arrow">left</div>
<div id="right_arrow">right</div>
<div id="acct_num"></div>
```

When the user clicks any arrow, it just updates num variable and sets timeout. Then the timeout calls your saveNum() function in 3 seconds. When the user clicks again on any arrow before timeout, it just updates the num variable and resets timeout. The timeout is fired only if there is no click for 3 seconds or when user leaves page.

Comment: What about disabling the click button for a certain amount of time on the first click?

Comment: Users need to be able to click it freely.  Once they are done clicking then I want to save it.